# How to customise the UIDatePicker components in swift?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker, uidatepickermodetime

For custom date picker I am using the

https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift

its working fine but I need to add two things on this

1.I need to re arrange the components order like **date/month/year(i.e 23/05/2016)** **instead of** **the month/date/year(i.e 05/23/2016)**.

2.I need another **datepicker object with only two components i.e month/year (may/2016)**.

How can I achieve  this

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand why down vote for my question

Comment: Try the attributes inspector in Xcode

Comment: @TomWolters sorry for lately reply . Here I am not using Storyboard. so how can I set the components

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `UIDatePicker`, and since that project uses `UIDatePicker`, you can't do it with that project.

`UIDatePicker` has extremely limited customization options. You can have it show a date, or a time, or both. But you can't tell it **how** to display the date, so you can't rearrange the components or choose which date components to show.

If you need these formats, you will need use `UIPickerView` and implement your own `delegate` and `dataSource` methods to display the options that you need. Or maybe you can find a different open source project that does what you need.

Comment: sorry for lately reply to you. Now I will work on UIDatePickerView and then I will update my status. thank you

Comment: after a hours of searching google I am getting one free controller for  only MONTH/YEAR format  https://github.com/jeksys/UIMonthYearPicker but its not working ,  it is crashed if I run the above project. Thank you

Comment: Solved my problem, I recheck the delegate and datasource connections my of UIPickerView in  storyboard then finally I got a picker view with MAY/2016 MONTH/YEAR format.